# Kotlin/JVM or Kotlin (Java) -- IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

when creating new project i am seeing only Groovy and Kotlin/JVM under additional libraries and frameworks in the tab. however, on the online course video, the lecturer selected kotlin (java) and i think he also have another unselected option as kotlin (java fx). why am I not seeing those options? I am using windows by the way.

Comment: What version and type(community, ultimate) of Intellij IDEA are you using?

Comment: Update your IntelliJ IDEA and Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Besides, the title doesn't match the content.

Comment: I am using 2018.3.5 (Community Edition) which is the latest version.

Comment: Also, when I type java -version in cmd it displays: java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode) BUT when I type javac -version , it displays javac 1.8.0_121 , is this the issue? because it shows two different versions. if so , how can this be rectified?

Comment: The Kotlin plugin version is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a guide that will help:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html

also this is something useful to have on your machine - it will help you manage multiple versions of various sdks

https://sdkman.io/